# 'catch' block is unreachable

Tags: ios, swift, try-catch

Why compiler shows warning `'catch' block is unreachable`?

It has a possibility an observer is not set, and then it will cause crash.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The yellow warning tells you why - nothing in the `do` block `throws`; you have no `try` statements, because none of the functions you are calling `throw`.  If nothing `throws` then you can never `catch`.

In Swift, do/try/catch, is only for catching Swift `Error`s.  It is not used for catching generic runtime exceptions that may occur.

`removeObserver` is a foundation function that predates Swift by a long time.  It will cause a hard runtime exception if the observer is not registered.  It does not throw a Swift `Error`.

Comment: I though Swift do/catch is more useful.

Comment: It generally is, but Key-Value observing is buried deep in `NSObject` and uses method substitution.  I would avoid it if at all possible.  You need to *know* whether you have an observer registered before un-registering.  You can't just try and hope it works.

Comment: "In Swift, do/try/catch, is only for catching Swift Errors. It is not used for catching generic runtime exceptions that may occur." amyve it should not but it does catch generic exceptions from objc runtime just fine. In Xcode 10.2.1 and swift 5 anyway